# Maclaurin series without Bernoulli or Euler numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, bernoulli-numbers, euler-maclaurin

I've been working through these listed [Maclaurin series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) and deriving all of them. For the listed trigonometric functions, I'm wondering if there are ways to do things:

1. not have Bernoulli or Euler numbers in the series
2. find the series without having to do polynomial division

- $\sec x$
- $\operatorname{sech} x$
- $\tan x$
- $\tanh x$

Additionally, on the [list of mathematical series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Trigonometric,_inverse_trigonometric,_hyperbolic,_and_inverse_hyperbolic_functions_relationship) for wikipedia, the following also have Bernoulli numbers:

- $\cot z$
- $\csc z$
- $\coth z$
- $\operatorname{csch} z$

I'm sure I could find them by doing division, but is there a better way? (And by "better way", I mean a connection between other series, like how $\sinh x$ can be made up of variations of $e^x$, or how $\sin^{-1} x$ can be found by manipulating binomial series)

In an earlier question of mine ([Two versions of Maclaurin series for $\arcsin(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703912/two-versions-of-maclaurin-series-for-arcsinx)), I learned that there's a way to not have the gamma function and so now I'm able to find that series -- but is there a way to not have these Bernoulli or Euler numbers (and is that way understandable at a single-variable calculus level?)

Comment: Is having a recurrence for the coefficients fine?

Comment: @Gary, I think recurrence for the coefficients could be okay since that is likely within high school and first year university level.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4724105) for an example.

Comment: @Gary Okay, that makes sense, but I suppose my next question would be if there's a way to have the coefficients be expressed in a non-recurrence way? But, knowing my line of inquiry,  even if there was, I'd wonder if there was an easier way. Basically,  the heart of my question is "could I have a 'nice' series for these above functions like how there are 'nice' series for the others, where the only new variable is $n$ due to the series notation?" Is there something about these above series that make it so they can't be expressed in somewhat simple series?

Comment: Well, the coefficients of a power series of an analytic function are uniquely determined. You can replace the Bernoulli or Euler numbers by one of their [explicit forms](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.6), but I am not sure if that makes things simpler. Indeed the coefficients of the Maclaurin series for, e.g., $\tan$ are not as nice as those for $\sin$ or $\cos$ but there is not much to do about it. They are what they are.

Comment: @Gary, that link is great but you're right that it's not particularly simpler. Every calculus textbook I've looked at has $\tan$ but none of them mention a "nice" series version. I suppose if there was, then it would have been mentioned. By chance with $\sin^{-1}$, after looking at textbooks and asking here, there was a lucky situation with the $\Gamma$ function being replaced with something simpler. I sorta hoped such replacement and simplification could be done with Bernoulli and Euler numbers if only I knew more math -- but it doesn't seem possible? Either way, thanks for the insights!

Comment: No, it is not possible. Otherwise we would not introduce those notations.

Comment: You can have nice series, so long as you aren't married to *power* series specifically. For example, $$\cot x = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2-n^2\pi^2}$$

Comment: To NinadMunshi, I'm basing my work off of Taylor series, so I'm only considering power series.
-
@Gary (or anyone else who could answer), considering hypergeometric series (from equation 41 on the mathworld link), would there be a way to make hypergeometric version of those first four trig functions? Right now, for example, I could make $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ and then substitute the hypergeometric series for $\cos(x)$ but the situation of non-simplification occurs. (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4729642/454931 for series of $\cos(x)$) Explicitly, no "simple" hypergeometric formula.